# HTML tags converting into entity characters in XSS

Tags: xss, html

When I type `xss` in a search box, it's reflecting[image] and when I inspect it, it's showing as `<h1>Search results for: xss</h1>`.[image]

So I tried to inject script `<img src=x onerror=alert(1)>` and it wasn't working and the `<>` is converted to entity characters.

So I tried another way `</h1><img src=x onerror=alert(1)>`. The `</h1>` for closing the `<h1>` tag so my script could work properly. But it still was not working and when I inspect it, `</h1>` and all other tags converted into entity characters.

I've tried other ways but it's not working.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. You typed in `Hello World!` and it formatted it as `<h1>Hello World!</h1>`? Is that the normal function of the site? Or have you omitted some crucial details?

Comment: @schroeder I'm actually new, maybe you are not understanding me. The website I was trying for bug was made on wordpress. Idk maybe it's wordpress policy to reflect the searched text in a "h1" tag. But when I was trying to inject any code it's not accepting it and turning it's <> into entities "&lt:&gt:". So how can I inject the code which can bypass this encoding system? I don't even know you can see my comment or not cause my post closed, just hopping.

Comment: Nothing in any of those screenshots show that *anything* is reflecting. It's merely formatting the text in line with its CSS.

Comment: So, there is no indication that there is a XSS vulnerability. What you appear to want to know is how to bypass the entity encoding function. OWASP (and a thousand other places on the internet) has cheatsheets for you to test if a bypass is possible.

Comment: I'm actually newbie and I'm so confused, I don't know where to start. I directly jumped into XSS cause I'm web designer so I understand web mechanisms. But now I see this is not that easy how I thought.  
  
I'm a self learner. So,
Can you please guide me the whole path for Bug Bounty as a "Roadmap"

Comment: There are thousands of tutorials, courses, books, attackable VMs and entire websites dedicated to teaching people how to perform XSS attacks. "Can you please guide me the whole path for Bug Bounty as a "Roadmap"" -- seriously?